# job with quartz - error java ee

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I need create a project web (without maven and spring) with execute jobs. After search I tested quartz, but not work. Ever show me this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
the server is tomcat.
add this libs in my project: servlet-api-2.5, commons-collections-3.2.1 and quartz-1.6.3
I followed this tutorial: 
[Simple example for Quartz 2.2 and Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573457/simple-example-for-quartz-2-2-and-tomcat-7)
and 
http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/how-to-create-web-app-with-quartz.html

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend that you use the latest Quartz version. 1.6.3 is at least 6 years old release. The latest Quartz release is 2.2.1. If you get the ClassNotFoundException, it means that the org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener class in on on your web-application's classpath. Make sure the quartz JAR is located inside WEB-INF/lib folder in your WAR file.