# How to write a Quartz timer service that updates every 6 months?

Tags: mysql, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-data-jpa

I want a Quartz timer service for the update code below. Every six months, all users' keys should be updated according to their `creationDate`:

```
//dataTypes are date only

List<User> allDbUsers=userRepository.findAll();

Date currDate=new Date();
final long DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
for(User user:allDbUsers)
{
    Date creationDate=user.getCreationDate();
    String firstKey=user.getFirstKey();

    Long diffInDays=(currDate.getTime()-creationDate.getTime())/DAY_IN_MILLIS;
    if(diffInDays==180)
    {
        user.setSecondKey(firstKey);
        user.setFirstKey("aH&#KK");
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a scheduler? Try to guess what happens if you schedule a job to run 180 days from now but your app gets restarted, say, once a month.

Comment: @kryger, his code not for run scheduler, it code for method job.excecute(what job must do). Scheduler should run every midnight(for example),  then there will be problems if the server stops , after the launch night job will call again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Calendar` for view diff between dates, for example:

```
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar sixMonthAfterCreation;

    for (User user : allDbUsers) {
        sixMonthAfterCreation = Calendar.getInstance()
        sixMonthAfterCreation.setTime(user.getCreationDate());
        sixMonthAfterCreation.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);

        String firstKey = user.getFirstKey();

        if (currentDate.after(sixMonthAfterCreation)) {
            user.setSecondKey(firstKey);
            user.setFirstKey("aH&#KK");
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        }
    }
```

or if you use java 8 you can convert you creation date to LocalDate and view diff.

If I right understand you, you want use Quartz Scheduler. I did not use it but I think you need implement `org.quartz.Job`, override `execute` method and write code for updating users in it.

For more information about Quartz Scheduler look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573457/simple-example-for-quartz-2-2-and-tomcat-7)

One clarification this code not for run scheduler, it code for method `job.excecute`(what job must do). Scheduler should run every midnight(for example), then every midnight will be called `execute` method which find all user for update and do it.

Comment: hey Oleg Naumov thanks a ton for your time i am using java 8 but i need same code for exact (date,time with second) execution through Timer Quartz service how can we migrate this code for timer service i am using spring 4.2 annotations

Comment: @D.K. I updated my answer, sorry if it not helpful for you

Comment: hi Oleg Naumov thank you for your update it is really helpful because in my previous code i was not getting exact time

Comment: Hii all it is not adding exact 6 months on whatever date i am getting from database can anyone help ?? I am getting month that is not correct means 1 month less it is comming