# Quartz job not started - Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, jobs, quartz

i'm trying to upload a project that can run a job every X hour of the day to a web server.

The problem is, when i'm running the project on my local (netbeans, apache 7) it's launched without problem and doing the job everytime i need, but if i deploy my war into a web server (Tomcat 8), it wont start.

i've seen some examples and some are adding a quartz.properties and a web.xml under WEB-INF/class/

My project

```
ProjectName
  ->Web pages
     -->META-INF
     -->WEB-INF
     -->index.jsp
  ->Source Packages
     -->job(package)
         --->Job.java
     -->main.java
```

> main class

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(
                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/15 * * * * ?")
            )
            .build();

    //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

}
```

}

> Job class

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

    System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");

}
```

}

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What are the logs saying??

Comment: if you haven't already.. check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573457/simple-example-for-quartz-2-2-and-tomcat-7
maybe that helps

Comment: No logs because it's not starting anything

Comment: @AxelM Thanx, i'm jus reading that, so i need to configure quartz.properties, quartz-data, log4j and a listener inside a web.xml.. thank you.

Comment: I think the answer describes two different approaches, if i got i correctly on a quick view, then you should be fine with the listener, no need for the other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best way to solve it but, i made it by creating a jsp that calls the method with the cron.

so, deploy --> call the jsp --> method --> cron.

The cron wasn't excecuted by anything before that.

Thank you all!